# How to use custom class created by ObjectARX

Tags: c#, autocad, objectarx

I want to develop an AutoCAD plugin. The main code use C#, but I need a custom class (an object consists of a text and some ), then I create a custom class with ObjectARX. After compilation, ObjectARX produces a .dbx and .lib file, but C# use .dll files. I don't know how to use this custom class with C#.

I tried to use hybrid programming, but immediately I realised that is was illogical, and also I couldn't find a similar example like this.

Comment: You need to put more information in your question 
please give us more input so we can help you

Comment: @Hicham Bouchikhi
I don’t understand why questions like this are closed, it’s a perfectly valid question

Comment: The answer is: after you create your custom object in ObjectARX, you must create a wrapper for C# to consume.
There’s a sample in the SDK. (samples\entity\polysamp)